# Relation between core mass and red giant mass?

Tags: star, mass, mathematics, nucleosynthesis, core

Yes, the title might be confusing (I'd appreciate some more clarification on it :D ). I have an estimated mass of hydrogen in the core of a star, and how much hydrogen will be in the core when the star leaves the main sequence. Is there a relationship between these or a defining or approximate equation, and are there any known values for given overall mass of a star?